# Trying to create a crude send/receive through TCP in python

Tags: python, tcp

So far I can send files to my "fileserver" and retrieve files from there as well. But i can't do both at the same time. I have to comment out one of the other threads for them to work. As you will see in my code.

SERVER CODE

```py
from socket import *
import threading
import os

# Send file function
def SendFile (name, sock):
filename = sock.recv(1024)      
  if os.path.isfile(filename):    
    sock.send("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))) 
    userResponse = sock.recv(1024)      
    if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':        
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
            sock.send(bytesToSend)
            while bytesToSend != "":   
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
else:                                   
    sock.send('ERROR')

sock.close()

def RetrFile (name, sock):
  filename = sock.recv(1024)      
  data = sock.recv(1024)                     
     if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':            
       filesize = long(data[6:])       
       sock.send('OK')
       f = open('new_' + filename, 'wb')      
       data = sock.recv(1024)
       totalRecieved = len(data)               
       f.write(data)
       while totalRecieved < filesize:         
         data = sock.recv(1024)
         totalRecieved += len(data)
         f.write(data)

sock.close()



myHost = ''                             
myPort = 7005                           

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)     
s.bind((myHost, myPort))             

s.listen(5)

print("Server Started.")

while True:                             

connection, address = s.accept()
print("Client Connection at:", address)

#    u = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("retrThread", connection))
t = threading.Thread(target=SendFile, args=("sendThread", connection))     
#    u.start()
t.start()


s.close()
```

CLIENT CODE

```py
from socket import *
import sys
import os

servHost = ''                          
servPort = 7005                         

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)        
s.connect((servHost, servPort))         

decision = raw_input("do you want to send or retrieve a file?(send/retrieve): ")

if decision == "retrieve" or decision == "Retrieve":
  filename = raw_input("Filename of file you want to retrieve from server: ")      # ask user for filename
  if filename != "q":                     
     s.send(filename)                    
     data = s.recv(1024)                 
     if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':           
        filesize = long(data[6:])       
        message = raw_input("File Exists, " + str(filesize)+"Bytes, download?: Y/N -> ")    

        if message == "Y" or message == "y":
            s.send('OK')
            f = open('new_' + filename, 'wb')       
            data = s.recv(1024)                     
            totalRecieved = len(data)               
            f.write(data)
            while totalRecieved < filesize:         
                data = s.recv(1024)
                totalRecieved += len(data)
                f.write(data)
                print("{0: .2f}".format((totalRecieved/float(filesize))*100)) + "% Done" # print % of download progress

            print("Download Done!")

    else:
        print("File does not exist!")
s.close()

elif decision == "send" or decision == "Send":
filename = raw_input("Filename of file you want to send to server: ")
if filename != "q":
    s.send(filename)                    
    if os.path.isfile(filename):    
        s.send("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))) 
        userResponse = s.recv(1024)      
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f: 
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                s.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":    
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    s.send(bytesToSend)
    else:                                   
        s.send('ERROR')

s.close()


s.close()
```

I'm still new to programming, so this is quite tough for me. All in all i'm just trying to figure out how to send AND receive files without having to comment out the bottom threads in my SERVER CODE.

Please and thank you!

Comment: This is not FTP, right? It's your custom protocol.

Comment: Yeah sorry if my terminology is off, probably not FTP.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you have two different threads trying to receive data from the same socket at the same time?

Comment: you're right, i created a new connection for the second thread and it works. now i'm limited to only using that thread for that connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just made an if statement sending a True or False and that will decide which thread to execute.

Answer (score 0):

On the serverside, you're trying to use the same connection for your two threads t and u.

I think it might work if you listened for another connection in your `while True:` loop on the server, after you started your first thread.

I always use the more high-level `socketserver` module ([Python Doc on socketserver](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example)), which also natively supports Threading. I recommend checking it out!

By the way, since you do a lot of `if (x == 'r' or x == 'R')`: you could just do `if x.lower() == 'r'`

Comment: So it looks like i'm able to make both threads work by just creating a new connection, as advised by people here. Is there anyway to make it so my threads can take either the second or first connection values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I'm guessing you want every thread to be capable of both retrieving and sending? In that case, I think it should be enough to unify your `SendFile` and `RetrFile` functions into *one* function, and give that to both your threads with `threading.Thread(target=UnifiedFunction)`. So rewrite your two functions into one, and after `filename = sock.recv(1024)` check if the file exists, if it does, send it, if it doesn't, continue with `data = sock.recv(1024)` and retrieve it.